# How do I import ruby classes into the main file?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to learn how to program with Ruby and I want to create separate files for separate classes, but when I do I get the following message:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Book
> const_missing at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2677
>
> (root) at /Users/Friso/Documents/Projects/RubyApplication1/lib/main.rb:1

However, it works if I put the class directly into the main file. How can I solve this?

Main code:

```
book1 = Book.new("1234", "Hello", "Ruby")
book2 = Book.new("4321", "World", "Rails")

book1.to_string
book2.to_string
```

Class code:

```
class Book
  def initialize(isbn,title,author)
    @book_isbn=isbn
    @book_title=title
    @book_author=author
  end
  
  def to_string
    puts "Title: #@book_title"
    puts "Author: #@book_author"
    puts "ISBN: #@book_isbn"
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you `require_relative`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In order to include classes, modules, etc into other files you have to use `require_relative` or `require` (`require_relative` is more Rubyish.) For example this module:

```
module Format

  def green(input)
    puts"\e[32m#{input}[0m\e"
  end
end
```

Now I have this file:

```
require_relative "format" #<= require the file

include Format #<= include the module

def example
  green("this will be green") #<= call the formatting 
end
```

The same concept goes for classes:

```
class Example

  attr_accessor :input

  def initialize(input)
    @input = input
  end

  def prompt
    print "#{@input}: "
    gets.chomp
  end
end

example = Example.new(ARGV[0])
```

And now I have the main file:

```
require_relative "class_example"

example.prompt
```

In order to call any class, or module from another file, you have to require it.

I hope this helps, and answers your question.

Answer (score 12):

You need to instruct the Ruby runtime to load the file that contains your Book class. You can do this with `require` or `require_relative`.

The latter is better in this case, because it loads the file relative to the directory in which the file containing the `require` is specified.  Since that's probably the same directory, you can just `require_relative` the file name, without the `.rb` extension by convention.

You can google 'require vs require_relative ruby' to find out more about the differences.

Comment: This is more descriptive of the differences than mine is, an easy way to remember which one to use is like how I was taught, require is for gems and require_relative is for files

Comment: There are times when you want to use `require` for files though. I'd say in general use `require` unless you have a problem, otherwise use `require_relative`. You could also use `require_relative` if you need to make sure where the file is being loaded from, as opposed to having it be loaded from anywhere in the load paths.